# When I write emails, how do I say my name?

Tags: politeness, email

I am a non-native English speaker.

While making a phone call, I should say,
"This is Julie Park." That is what my English text book says.

But when I am sending an email, what should I say?

1) This is Julie Park

or

2) I am Julie Park....

Comment: Depends on the email. Generally in mail, you use an initial salutation to the person you're sending the mail to, and you use your name in the closing. Depending on who's getting the mail, that could be "Julie", "Jules", "Ms Park", "Ms Julie Park", or "Julie Park, PhD". Assuming you have a PhD, of course.

Comment: How would you do it in an email written in your native language?

Answer (score 3):

Emails are not like phone calls; they are more like letters.

With email, the recipient can see your email address or, in some cases, your name before reading the email. (For a letter, you would add a return address on the envelope.)

Just like with letter writing, it is typical to sign your name at the very bottom of an email. If you enable the option to automatically add a signature (which most email apps have), it will be added at the bottom.

---

The exact way you sign will depend on context.

If you're writing an informal email, you might write only your first name, first initial, or not include a signature at all. Chances are, your friends recognize your email. With informal email, you have a lot of freedom all around, but most people will expect a signature to be at the end (if you include one).

I also don't bother writing my name (or anything much) if I'm sending emails during a conversation with the person. Usually this comes up when working on separate computers, and a file needs to be transferred.

---

There are two different levels of formal email, at least in my mind.

If it's more casual, such as an email from me to my professor, I will sign it with just my name at the bottom (and I also exclude the "Dear" at the beginning). I may or may not sign my last name, depending on how well they know me (since my name is unique).

In a really formal email, such as one to a company with a job application, I sign with some variant of:

> Sincerely,
>   Name LastName

You can read more about formal email writing [here](http://www.wikihow.com/Write-a-Formal-Email).

Answer (score 1):

I write for my student paper at my university, and so I often have to email professors to ask them to speak with me. Since professors are busy people, I like to introduce myself first so they know what the context of the email is. I already have to say "I'm a writer for [our student paper]," so I introduce my name at the same time.

The most colloquial way, I feel (as an AmE) speaker, is to start off

> Hello,
>
> My name is Azor-Ahai, and I'm a writer for [our student paper] ...

It gives a little bit of context and personalizes the email, but your situation will depend on who you're writing to, and at what level of formality. Do they know who you are? For a "cold call," an up-front introduction might be best, but emailing a person you regularly work with wouldn't require it.

Answer (score 0):

I think people usually don't say their name first. They tend to write their name in the end (Personal understanding). The people that around me do that.
Like normally.
People would write regards, and name
But the name is at next row.
You could search online to find an image of Email format

Comment: I make a point (pun intended) of announcing my first name at the beginning rather than at the end of e-mail. Thus "Greetings from Peter" often occupies the e-mail's subject line, making my presence in cyberspace known to the recipient as he/she glances down the screen at the rows of incoming e-mails. Additionally, I might commence the text of my e-mail with the same salutation. I sign off with "Best wishes" or Kind regards, with my first name or merely my initial, "P" But these things are fairly flexible and subject to personal whim, etc.

Comment: @PeterPoint Yours answer is better than mine.

Comment: I think the decision to put the name first depends on the "expectedness" of the email.  If you're emailing someone "out of the blue", and they don't know who you are, it can be polite to introduce yourself at the start.  You might add a bit of explanation about who you are, for example *"Hi Kurt - my name's Yon Yonson: I work at the Wisconsin lumbermill".*  This sets a more friendly tone for the rest of the email.